# Twitter-bootstrap "affix" is not affixing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In implementing a search functionality, I'm returning dynamically generated html in response to an ajax request and inserting the HTML into a div.  Part of the dynamic HTML is a "navigation pane" that I want to affix using bootstrap (the "#affixcontainer" div).  However, the navigation pane refuses to stick.

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-xs-3">
    <div id="affixcontainer" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="120" data-offset-bottom="10">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">SEARCH RESULTS</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;margin:0">
                <nav id="scroll-nav" class="bs-docs-sidebar hidden-print hidden-xs" role="navigation"> 
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked bs-docs-sidenav"> 
                        <li><a href="#top"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>Top</a></li>
                        <li>Category 1</li>
                        <li>Category 2</li>
                        <li>Category 3</li>
                        <li>Category 4</li>
                        <li>Category 5</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9">
    SEARCH LISTINGS
</div>
```

I also tried to affix using javascript (separately, see code snipped below), but that doesn't seem to work either.  The script is at the bottom of the dynamically generated HTMl. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#affixcontainer").affix({
        offset: {
            top: 120,
            bottom: 20
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the HTML above is the HTML that is being dynamically inserted. The `.affix()` function would need to be called after it is appended to the DOM. The `data-` attributes only work for elements available on page load. Anything inserted after that require a separate call to `affix()`. See 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/js/affix.js#L148 for it's implementation.

**EDIT**

Also, `$(document).ready()` does not work since AJAX calls occurs after this event. The HTML elements would not be in the DOM yet.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Ok.  Based on that, I called the .affix function from the success:function(result) for the JQUERY .ajax call and that worked.  Thanks!